# Connecting Router with DHCP to Modem over LAN (no WAN)

Tags: networking, router, dns, wireless-access-point, modem

I have a TP-Link router and a technicolor cable modem. I have set up the router as a wireless access point using this tutorial:

https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-417.html

The only reason I made it into a simple AP, with DHCP turned off, is because it is connected to the router (which is in another room, with cables going through walls) over LAN and this was the only tutorial showing how to connect both without WAN.

Now I want to utilize the DNS configuration in the TP-Link-modem for setting up a Raspberry-Pi Pi-Hole as DNS-Server, but I am not able to do that without turning on DHCP again. Is there a way for me to use DHCP without WAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the primary firewall/gateway/router that serves this LAN then you can simply use your TP-Link box as firewall/router instead of Access Point. Simply plug cable from your LAN to WAN port on TP-Link and you good to go.

The only think that you need to keep in mind - LAN network schema of your router must not be the same as primary LAN. For example if primary LAN used 192.168.1.0/24 and you router has the same as default, then you need to change on your TP-Link LAN network to something different, say 192.168.99.0/24 then plug WAN port of your TP-Link to the primary LAN. This way you can use DHCP of your router and having access to the primary network you are originally connected

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to do this with the same type of Ethernet cable? The WAN-ports on my hardware require a different cable that I would need to move through three rooms. So there is no option using the LAN port?

Comment: This is not really the question, so sorry, but would a Cat6 Crossover adapter work for me?

Comment: I afraid you din't understand, you don't need to run extra cable, just plug cable that you plugged now to LAN to WAN, just re-plug it on TP-Link and use it as router instead of Access point

Comment: Most nowadays network equipment supports MDI auto negotiation, so its don't care if it crossover or normal cable

Comment: But the WAN has a different socket, it doesn't fit at all

Comment: Take a look closer, blue WAN port is the same ethernet port as on LAN sockets according to link you provided to your equipment !

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that, I could find only a tutorial for other TP-Link models. Mine has an ADSL socket for WAN

Comment: I think I mistook the ADSL socket for WAN. I will try out if the first out of the four Cat sockets for using as WAN, this is how these things are designed

Comment: What is exact model number/name of your TP-Link router?